# R - Graph font problems

Tags: r

```
#test.R
x <- y <- seq(10,70,10)

png("test.png")
plot(x, y, type='o', col='red')
grid()

title(main="title", font.main=5)
title(xlab="B", col.lab="black")
title(ylab="C", col.lab="black")
```

**test OS:** CentOS 7, Debian 8.1

run following command. 
Rscript test.R --> create test.png.

my graph is odd. 
Title, x and y axis chacter are not english. 
How can print the normal english chracter?

[image]

Comment: From `?par`, the `font` section: *font 5 is expected to be the symbol font*. Nothing surprising if you choose `font.main = 5`. You should choose 1, 2, 3 or 4.

Answer (score 1):

From `?par`, the `font` section: *font 5 is expected to be the symbol font*. Nothing surprising if you choose font.main = 5. You should choose 1, 2, 3 or 4

```
x <- y <- seq(10,70,10)
par(mfrow=c(2,3), mar=c(4,4,3,3))
for(i in 1:5){
  plot(x, y, type='o', col='red', xlab = "", ylab = "")
  grid()
  title(main="title", xlab="B", ylab="C", font.main=i)
}
```

[image]